# SimpleDateFormat ParseException for "11 Jan 2015 15:56:00 +0100" format "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

Tags: java, android

Why I receive
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11 Jan 2015 15:56:00" (at offset 0)
for 
"11 Jan 2015 15:56:00 +0100" ?!

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
                Date pubDate = null;
                try {
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
                    pubDate = dateFormat.parse("11 Jan 2015 15:56:00 +0100");
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
                // convert to format dd/mm/yyyy
                this.pubDate = dateFormat.format(pubDate);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: simply because your pattern does not match your date.

Comment: Also your  `parse(this.pubDate)` would not compile because `parse` doesn't take `Date` and your `dateFormat.format(pubDate)` would not return a `Date` but a `String`

Comment: this.pubDate is String type. this.pubDate is not local pubDate declared. It compiles

You two guys are wrong) rgettman wins!=) he was right about EEE
But thanks all for asnwering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format portion "EEE" means "Day name in week", according to [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but there is no day of week in the string `"11 Jan 2015 15:56:00"`.

Remove the "EEE" portion of the date format (or prepend the day of the week in the string), and then it should parse correctly.

Comment: rgettman, thank you very much!! you are absolutely right! you answer helped